# MongoDB Service at 100% CPU

Tags: mongodb, windows-services, cpu-usage

I'm starting to learn to use MongoDB and are trying to get a local server running, but when I run the command to install the service:

> mongod --install --serviceName MongoDB --serviceDisplayName MongoDB --logfile C:\MongoDB\log.log

And start the service, it uses 100% CPU and consequently my workstation sounds like its taking off.

I haven't even done anything yet and it's running at 100% CPU. This is on 32-bit Windows 7 with a Core 2 Duo 3.16GHz and 4GB ram.

I've tried searching Google, but none of the high CPU usage results lead to anything.

Comment: Have you moved/copied your mongo database from another server/pc? I had an issue when I copied the db directory from one pc to another and didnt delete the mongod.lock file. The service just got stuck trying to start

Comment: This is a fresh install with no data whatsoever. It's like a brand new engine with a stuck accelerator at maximum.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes MongoDB has issues with the lock file in the data folder if it wasn't closed cleanly. Make sure that the lock file does not exist before attempting to start the service.

If this is the problem, you can usually observe the behavior by watching the process in Task Manager and observing the PID in a constant state of flux.

Comment: Downvote? It's an answer based on real experience. Comment to help explain why this should be downvoted would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't even find the process that is taking 100% of CPU. And also, this is from a clean install. It only has ever run at full load.

Comment: This is a valid answer in some cases, I have seen this happen with the mongo lock file

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you install command I think you have an incorrect switch

`--logfile` doesnt appear to be a valid switch.

Try installing the service using the following, I use the following command for setting up a quick install of the service. Would need tweaking for a production environment.

```
mongod.exe -v --logpath C:\MongoDB\log.log --logappend --dbpath $mongoDBLocation --install
```

We are using Version 2.0.4 currently so hopefully it this will work for you.